# Accessing a SQL Server from a .Net app running inside a Docker container

Tags: sql-server, docker

I have created a .Net Core app and I have generated a Dockerfile using Visual Studio. The app is able to access databases hosted in a server on cloud when the ip address username and password are provided to it, when I run it using Visual Studio 2015.

But the problem arises when I try and use the same app in a Docker Container.

The app inside the container is unable to find the ip address for some reason even though I am able to ping the server from my Docker quick start terminal.

The error I get when I inspect the container goes something like this

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL server is configured"

I get this error when I try to connect when the app is in the container but the app is able to connect to the sql server when the app is running inside VS 2015

So is there any solution where I can check if the container is able to access SQL Server. If so what is it?

If an example can be provided about how we can get containers to access servers outside it would be of great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you include the error you're getting when you're trying to connect?

Comment: There is no version **2016** of Visual Studio - we had 2010, 2012, 2013 and now 2015 - which one are you actually using?

Comment: sorry about the confusion I am using the 2015 VS for core applications

Comment: I have added the error I had on inspection thanks.